# htaccess does not work correctly on my site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site based on PHP and Amazon api and I can not get it to work properly. Missing something in htaccess code.

Site => kinyti.com (OK)

Search page => kinyti.com/list?searchindex=All&search_term=samsung (OK)

Product => kinyti.com/product/B073TLKQB9 (file not found)

**htaccess in use:**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
AcceptPathInfo On
# multiviews functionality
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/?)(.*?)$ $1.php$2$3 [L]
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: What's the problem and what's the expected behavior?

Comment: Make the product page open properly. Is showing the error "file not found"

Comment: you need to Enable .htaccess in your  Apache server

Comment: htaccess enabled. I use another scripts in the same server

Comment: your rule will rewrite to `kinyti.com.php/product/B073TLKQB9`